# creating a liquid fillstyle for images in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When handling my health bar I use this code

```
bar.rectTransform.localScale = new Vector3(currentValue / maxValue, 1, 1);
```

and this works pretty fine. But the fill style is linear. How can I set a custom fillstyle with some liquid effects?

There should be added some "water effects" with small waves.

[image]

Comment: I've used different sprites to get that effect. Like per %1 I've used a sprite which left side is up and mid side is up and right side is up. So in the end when you play the whole sprites like an old cartoon technique, I've got the effect which looks like a fluid was moving up and down. Also, you can create another sprite with the animation on top, bottom part will be linear, even though the level is not changing the top part will always animate like a fluid

Comment: This could be handled with a nice shader to give it the "volume" and "fluid" visual style and then animating the texture to scroll up or down infinitely. The animation would probably look kinda cheap and "developed", but it could definitely work.

Comment: So I think I [wrote a shader](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/vfx/shaders/alpha-cutout-shaders-16429) that *might* work for this. I haven't tried giving it an *intentionally* wiggly edge, but if you look at one of the example screenshots (the green vertical bars), you can see that the standard cutout shader has some pixel noise to it. If you did that *intentionally* and applied the blur (the right bar, but to a less extreme degree) it might look pretty good. You could then animate it by using UV manipulation. (The default cutout shader might work for you too).